# How to get multiple checkbox value and assign to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, spring-mvc

I want to store the multiple **id** to hidden field.
So value able to bind to controller.

```
<form:hidden id="ids" path="ids" value="${ids }"/>
```

When click button delete will call jquery to delete row.

```
var deleteIds = [];
    $("#deleteRow").on('click', function() {
        deleteIds = $('.case:checkbox:checked').val();
        $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
        $('#ids').val(deleteIds);
    });
```

My question is

- How to set the value into ***ids***?

Thank You.

Comment: You want to retrieve the value of the field you're about to delete?

Comment: Hi @rafaelcpalmeida, I able retrieve value by this `deleteIds = $('.case:checkbox:checked').val();` Just I want to know how to store this deleteIds value into hidden field. And deleteIds can be many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to set the multiples value to hidden field. Answer as below.

```
 <form:hidden id="ids" path="ids" value="${ids }"/>



$("#deleteRow").on('click', function() {
                var deleteIds = [];
                $('.case:checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                    if($('#ids').val() != ''){
                deleteIds[i] = $('#ids').val() + "," + $(this).val();
            }else{
                deleteIds[i] = $(this).val();
            }
         });
        $('#ids').attr("value",deleteIds);
  });
```

The `each(function(i))` will loop all the checkbox and store in array[], after that assign the array to hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

The tag from doesn't have the attribute `value`. You can check the attributes for the form tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp).

However, you can use jQuery to modify custom attributes. Here's a working fiddle:

```js
var deleteIds = [];

deleteIds = ["1","2","3","4"];

$('#ids').attr("value",deleteIds);

alert($('#ids').attr("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ids" path="ids" value="${ids }"/>
```

Comment: Hmm. Actually I want store the value of checkbox(Tick 2 checkbox) to hidden field. So controller side able to retrieve the hidden value. Thanks.

Comment: You can store any value you want, the 5 there is just for testing purposes :)

Comment: Hi @rafaelcpalmeida, I still unable to store multiple ids into ${ids}.
When perform delete, it will call this function`$("#deleteRow").on('click', function() {` , I need to keep this `ids`(let say got 2 ids, "1", "2") until `SUBMIT` button clicked and then post to backend.

Comment: Hi @rafaelcpalmeida, Please see my answer below. Btw, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

By creating multiple `<form:hidden/>`, you can get what you want. I assume you when you click `#deleteRow`, table rows is deleted and you submit form of these ids to server, so we can make it by follow.

Cause I even don't know your html structure, so I've just tried to modify your script, may help you;)

```
var deleteIds = [];
$("#deleteRow").on('click', function() {
    $('#ids').remove();
    deleteIds = $('.case:checkbox:checked').val();
    $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < deleteIds.length; i++) {
        // formId should be replaced to your form id
        $('#formId').append('<form:hidden id="ids" path="ids" value="' + deleteIds[i] +'"/>');
    }
    // $('#formId').submit(); comment this line, cause there is another button to submit form.
});
```

Comment: I got delete button to delete the row from table. So it will call `$("#deleteRow").on('click', function() {`

After that click the SUBMIT button to submit to server. So server have to retrieve all the deleted ids.

Comment: @user1238353 If you used SpringMVC as your server, and it can accept multiple `ids` as a Array to handle your process.